# Adding to the basic entity frameword + crud

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I'm new to the .net framework but not to programming. I used the simple Crud generation with .net/c# and on the create view I would like to be able to have a dropdown list generated from a different model. I'm not sure how to achieve this with c#.net Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi user1121777 (couldn't resist)

If your drop-down list comes from a separate model (I do that myself), you can instantiate the context related to model#2, query for that drop-down list data as a No-Tracking query and then dispose that context.

How you do a no-tracking query is different if you are using an ObjectContext from how you do it with a DbContext.

For DbContext, you can use the AsNoTracking method extension on a linq query.

For ObjectCOntext it's a PIA. :)  Check this old article I wrote and if you search for the term "notracking" you'll see the basic pattern for that.

When you make a selection from the drop-down list, you can then use the key value of the selection and apply that to the related foreign key property of the object you are editing.

HTH
Julie